# WPF DataGridTextColumn multi-line input

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am using the WPF DataGrid control in .NET 4 that have a DataGridTextColumn.

I want to be able to enter multi-line text.
The line breaks are formatted correctly when I bind data to the column, but I've found no way of creating the line breaks when editing the text.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyMessages}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message" Binding="{Binding Path=Message}"  Width="Auto"/>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Message" Binding="{Binding Path=Message}"  Width="Auto">
        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="true" />
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Note: In my case this worked, but only if I set DataGrid.HorizontalScollBarVisibility = "Disabled" per http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e1b33317-e9ef-4b03-b173-c00aa22fb78d/  Once I did that my rows started resizing beautifully.

Comment: Is there anyone who has solved the syntax of doing this in a seperate style resource? I'm having this issue right now and cannot for the life of me find a working style resource to do this job!

Comment: In order to prevent character by character wrapping and enable space by space wrapping, use `Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
xmlns:wtk="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"

<DataTemplate x:Key="dataGridMultiLineTextBoxTemplateColumn" DataType="your data type">
        <wtk:MultiLineTextEditor
            x:Name="MultiLineTextBox"
            Width="300"
            Margin="2"
            Padding="5,0,0,0"
            FontSize="12"
            FontWeight="Normal"
            Foreground="Black"
            IsSpellCheckEnabled="True"
            Text="{Binding your binding property, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Extended WPF Toolkit MultiLineTextEditor will provide what you need.
[Extended WPF Toolkit MultiLineTextEditor](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MultiLineTextEditor&referringTitle=Home)

Comment: Can you expand on that?