# How to use a control equivalent to the WinForms DataGridView in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

I've been creating an inspection form using WPF and I need a place where users can type an unknown amount of comments (hence why I'm not using textboxes). In my WinForms version of this application, I used a DataGridView and I could enter in as much information as I wanted to. I'm looking to do the same with a DataGrid or an equivalent control in WPF.

### WinForms Example

[image: Inspection Form (WinForms)]

---

I need to be able to do the same thing in WPF but I can't seem to add any rows in the DataGrid. On top of that, when I try to check `CanUserAddRows` it unchecks it immediatly.

[image: Cannot add rows]

---

So I checked out [Vincent Sigal's blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vinsibal/overview-of-the-editing-features-in-the-wpf-datagrid) about this issue. He mentions something interesting:

> ... but beware of CanUserAddRows and CanUserDeleteRows as they can appear a little magical.  Their values are coerced based on other properties such as DataGrid.IsReadOnly, DataGrid.IsEnabled, IEditableCollectionView.CanAddNew, and IEditableCollectionView.CanRemove.  So this is another thing to watch out for when editing.  If you run into a situation where you set CanUserAddRows or CanUserDeleteRows to true but it is changed to false automatically, check that the conditions below are met.

I verified this and my DataGrid **is not read-only** and it **is enabled**. Although, I have no idea where to find the `IEditableCollectionView.CanAddNew` and `IEditableCollectionView.CanRemove` ...

I don't think my situation should require a binding event on the DataGrid since the user is supposed to enter his comments directly into the DataGrid ... Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Perhaps I should use a different control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to admit that I stopped reading through your question after the first paragraph, so please forgive me if I have understood you wrong... but if you just want to enter multi line text into a `TextBox` in WPF, you can do it by setting a couple of properties on it:

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" />
```

For a `DataGrid`, you can set these properties in the `DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle` and/or `DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle` as the [WPF DataGridTextColumn multi-line input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354694/wpf-datagridtextcolumn-multi-line-input) post shows quite nicely.

Please let me know if I *did* misunderstand you.

---

UPDATE >>>

Ok, so I came back to read the rest of your question... answering without reading the question can be risky business on this site. It's just as well that I did too, as I see you also want to know how to use the `DataGrid`.

I have to start by saying... take a deep breath... WPF is *very* different to WinForms... *very* different. In WPF we manipulate data rather than UI objects, so to add a new row actually means adding a new item to a collection. You can find a complete working example on the [`DataGrid` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) page on MSDN.

Please also view the [WPF DataGrid Control](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html) page on WPF Tutorial.NET for more examples. WPF has a lot to take in for new comers and can be quite bewildering, but it's well worth the trouble when you get into it.

Comment: Yes I believe you did misunderstand my question. I explain further down that I'm looking to replicate the WinForms DataGridView in WPF. Right now with WPF, I have a DataGrid but I can't type anything in it. I don't want to bind data to it because the user must enter his comments there... Perhaps there's a better  control suited for this that I haven't found yet.

Comment: Right I've read a lot that WPF is difficult for WinForm programmers at first. Should I instead provide another form to make the user add his data in separate textboxes and then when he accepts the data, it gets sent to a collection which would then be displayed?

Comment: @alex WPF is not difficult. WPF separates UI from Data, which is a concept that winforms developers cannot undertand. `I don't think my situation should require a binding` - Yes you need DataBinding, WPF is not intended to be used otherwise.

Comment: @HighCore I see. Thanks for the enlightenment!

Comment: I would recommend that you persevere with WPF... *unless you are really in a hurry to complete your current project*. Once you get used to it, you'll wonder why you wasted so much time on WinForms. :) [I may be somewhat biased on this subject.]

Comment: Care to leave a comment, down voter? It really is pointless down voting without commenting... you've achieved nothing... made no point.